# IIf in Field expression Returns Error ssrs2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

i have this expression in my `ssrs` Field expression:

```
iif(Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)<>0 ,
Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value *Fields!AchievedPCN.Value)/Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)
,0)
```

when `Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value) =0` and  `Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value *Fields!AchievedPCN.Value) =0` return `#Error`

why that happens? my `ssrs` version is 2008.

Comment: Are you sure your `ActualWeight.Value` and `AchievedPCN.Value` values are non zero and also make sure are they `string` type.

Comment: yes, i add to field that to show this values and that error occurs when Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value *Fields!AchievedPCN.Value) =0 and

Comment: If `Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value *Fields!AchievedPCN.Value) =0` this is true then error is bound to happen as 0 divided by any number would give infinity. SO if you can alter your condition in the expression to check directly for multiplication that would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after very tries i found that's solution:

```
=IIF((CInt(Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value))>0 
and CInt(Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value *Fields!AchievedPCN.Value))>0),
(Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value *Fields!AchievedPCN.Value))/iif(Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)=0,1,Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)),0)
```

i must add this to Denominator:

```
iif(Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)=0,1,Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)
```

instead of

```
Sum(Fields!ActualWeight.Value)
```